# Do namespaces render prototyping methods obsolete in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, prototype

I'm migrating to C++ from C and the very first thing I've noticed is the redundancy of prototyping inside of a namespace. I'm trying to utilize the functionality of namespaces to keep my additions/modifications clearly marked.

```
namespace ns {
    void sayHello (void);   //<-- NOT REQUIRED, BUT IS THERE ANY PURPOSE?
    void sayHello (void) {
        std::cout << "Hello world!";
        return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ns::sayHello();
}
```

Previously, in C, it was good measure to have a prototype so you would not be required to write your functions "above" main() in the source. It appears to me that namespaces must be defined before usage, so therefore, any nested functions would also be written before usage.

I'm just starting C++ and I want to start out correct. I've been reading several tutorials across the internet, but they don't really mention this topic. I know this is "simple", but please spare me the down votes and flip comments. If someone is able, I would appreciate a deeper discussion of whether or not this is obsolete, and/or scenarios this could end up biting a new C++ developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily. Declaration and definition are still different concepts. Also, note that a namespace can span through multiple files and definitions are not required to be in the namespace.

```
//test.h
namespace test
{
   void foo();
   //no implementation in header
}

//main.cpp
int main()
{
   test::foo();
   return 0;
}

//test.cpp
namespace test
{
   void foo() { };
   //definition here
   //without the definition, we'd get a link error
}
```

Separation of implementation in C++ is done for reasons like keeping your code secret, faster compilation (changing the definition in the header would require a re-compilation of all including files), hiding implementation details or a cleaner structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you split the header and implementation files, then the prototype is required.

Answer (score 0):

You put the declarations in a header file and the definitions in a source file, like

In e.g. ns.h:

```
namespace ns {
    void sayHello (void);
}
```

In ns.cc:

```
namespace ns {
    void sayHello (void) {
        std::cout << "Hello world!";
        return;
    }
}
```

In main.cc:

```
#include "ns.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ns::sayHello();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly your question. That said, namespaces didn't change the declaration/definition procedure of functions. The point of namespaces is just to make it possible for the compiler to understand which version of foo() you are calling if there are more than one in the files you are including.

About the example you made: if you put the definition right after the declaration, then the declaration is not needed anymore (the definition can work also as a declaration). You still need the prototype if you split declaration and definition in header and source files. By the way, this is recommended, since who uses your code just needs to include the headers (which tell the compiler "how your functions should be called"). The definition is just needed at linking time.

Hope I addressed at least a little bit your question... ;-)